# Getting NaN on some queues count on RabbitMQ WebUI

Tags: rabbitmq

Currently running version RabbitMQ: 3.6.16 Erlang 20.3.4,
Since yesterday night we're seeing this issue in RabbitMQ Webui that some of the queues are showing NaN, Also I attached the screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old issue. I'd suggest updating rabbitmq to the last version.
Currently, we are on 3.9.11. Your version is ~2 years old.